# What does zero mean in Handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)

Tags: android

I am learning Android and I am stuck at this statement.
From google:

> Sends a Message containing only the what value.
>
> Returns
>
> Returns true if the message was successfully placed in to the message
>   queue. Returns false on failure, usually because the looper processing
>   the message queue is exiting.

Someone please explains for me what the Message containing zero will do. Thanks

Comment: that's, like the doc says, message.what

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means the `what` value. `what` is basically an integer that allows the receiver to identify the messages it receives.

Your handleMessage function looks like this

```
public void handleMessage (Message msg)
```

you are passed a `Message` object and you can check the public field `what` to figure out what the message is about. (`msg.what`)

Eg.

you send two types of messages, with `what` value `1 for success` and `0 for failure`

so your handleMessage function would look something like this

```
public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            //success handling
            break;

        case 0:
            //failure handling
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you can have `sendEmptyMessage(0)` for success and `sendEmptyMessage(1)` for failure.

Remember, that you dont have to send an empty message, you can send a Message object with more data attached to it too

for example to send a message with some text on success you can do

```
Message.obtain(mHandler, 0, "Success text")
```

and similarly for failure

Now as per what the zero means, It is just sending an empty message and the 0 could be replaced by any value. The idea is in this case you have only one type of messages and the Handler does understands that. So it does not need to check what kind of message it has received it just needs to receive a message. So `sendEmptyMessage(AnyInteger)` would work fine. 0 is just by convention

Comment: They should put your explanation in their documentation, really helpful! But why do they call it `emptyMessage` when it's in fact an `oneIntMessage`?